# How to run behat-html-formatter in behat 3.5

Tags: html, windows, report, behat

I have behat 3.5 up and running fine on windows 10. Now I wish to publish test results in html format. I installed this plugin https://github.com/dutchiexl/BehatHtmlFormatterPlugin

But how do I run behat tests utilizing this plugin? If I type "behat" I only see test steps in text format on the console. If I type "behat --format html --out test.feature.html --config behat.yml" I get an html output that looks "ugly".

My composer.json:

```
{   
  "require": {       
        "behat/behat": "~3.0",      
        "behat/mink": "~1.7@dev",              
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.2.1",       
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.3.1" ,
        "behat/mink-extension": "*"
   },   
   "config": {       
        "bin-dir": "bin/"  
   },
   "require-dev": {
        "emuse/behat-html-formatter": "^0.2.0"
   }
}
```

My behat.yml:

```
default:
        extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension:
                default_session: goutte
                goutte: ~
                selenium2: 
                  wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
                  capabilities: { "browserName": "firefox", "browser": "firefox", "version":  "", "platform": "WINDOWS" }
                browser_name: firefox
                emuse\BehatHTMLFormatter\BehatHTMLFormatterExtension:
                    name: html
                    renderer: Twig,Behat2
                    file_name: index
                    print_args: true
                    print_outp: true
                    loop_break: true
        suites:
            default:
                contexts:
                  - emuse\BehatHTMLFormatter\Context\ScreenshotContext:
                        screenshotDir: build/html/behat/assets/screenshots
                    - FeatureContext
            formatters:
                html:
                    output_path: %paths.base%/build/html/behat
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the details to make this work at https://packagist.org/packages/emuse/behat-html-formatter - I am using behat 3.6.1

After installing the html formatter with composer: `composer require --dev emuse/behat-html-formatter` I made my behat.html file look like this:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
        - emuse\BehatHTMLFormatter\Context\ScreenshotContext:
            screenshotDir: report/html/behat/assets/screenshots
  formatters:
    html:
      output_path: report/html/behat
  extensions:
    Drupal\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
      base_url: http://tea.ddev.site
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
    emuse\BehatHTMLFormatter\BehatHTMLFormatterExtension:
      name: html
      renderer: Twig,Behat2
      file_name: index
      print_args: true
      print_outp: true
      loop_break: true
```

Now when I run the behat tests, the output goes to behat/report/html/behat/index.html
I don't need to specify the output as html, it automatically does that.